# Event when view is rendered on NativeScript

Tags: events, view, interface, render, nativescript

How can I start a function after view is rendered? I need to get for example measured width of some component but everything is 0 or NaN at least when accessed from `navigatedTo` and `loaded` events.

Comment: proive actual code of what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You could use a timer with a setTimeout of 1 millisecond. This code will be executed after everything code is executed / rendered.

Comment: I'm trying to get view dimensions, not much code there yet. I will try that timer delay idea out.

Answer (score 4):

Do to the timing of when things are built and drawn; the only method that I have found to reliably work is actually using something like:

```
exports.onNavigatingTo = function() {
  setTimeout(codeAfterRender, 1);
}

function codeAfterRender() {
/* do something cool */
}
```

The reason why is because just like a normal app the UI is still only a single thread; so while JS is running; the UI can't actually update.

So the trick is to push off your code until AFTER the JS engine exits back to native code; native code renders the screen and then re-enters the JS engine.

So the simplest method to delay your code is to use a setTimeout as setTimeout is scheduled in native code.   (This is very much like using process.nextTick in Node.)

Event loop:

- JavaScript Code
- JavaScript Code -> You Schedule Timeout (which is actually scheduled in Native)
- JavaScript Code Finishes all execution
- JavaScript runtime returns back to Native Code
- Native Code Renders and processes all messages remaining.
- Native Code timer fires, starts JS engine up passing your setTimeout function
- JavaScript Code starts your setTimeout routine
- JavaScript Code finishes, exits back to NativeCode
- Native Code renders and processes all messages remaining
- Native Code goes idle.

Just for some additional clarity; on how the event loop works, a real example; One helper routine I wrote for one of my apps is like so:

```
function updateProgress(msg) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            statusLabel.text = msg;
            setTimeout(resolve, 0);
        });
}
```

So I would do this type of code.

```
UpdateProgress("Processing 1/3")
.then(function() {
 /* do some work, work freezes UI, so break it up */ 
  return UpdateProgress("Processing 2/3");
})
.then(function() {
  /* do some more work, again work freezes UI */
  return UpdateProgress("Processing 3/3");
})
.then(function() {
  /* do some more work, again work freezes UI */
  return ...
});
```

The reason why is because while NativeScript is still in the JavaScript part of the eventloop the display is NOT updated; so if you have lots of work to do and you still want the display to be responsive you need to exit the JavaScript part of the event loop; let the Native part handle any pending messages then resume back in the JS part for the next part of the processing.    (This also eliminates ANR's on Android) -- So the trick is having the `Resolve` call is handled via a setTimeout.

I have also seen some people use the on idle notification; however it is a bit more complex to setup the events for that on both platforms; using `setTimeout` is simpler and works equally well.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Does this mean that `setTimeout(codeAfterRender, 0);` would be equally as effective?

Comment: Yep, 0 works as well.   Won't really be any difference, 0 or 1 millisecond identical when you are throwing off work; by the time the JS engine exits and goes to native; you've used at least 1 ms.  ;-)      The only reason I prefer 1 over 0 is just in case someone uses a falsy test in a setTimeout monkeypatch or in the runtimes; my code will still continue to run.    Probably a very very very remote possibility; but I always hedge my bets...  ;-)

Comment: I think personally I'm going to prefer `setTimeout(codeAfterRender, 0);`, so the intent of the code is more clear to the reader - that this is not used to introduce an intentional delay.
Thank you for your awesome answer!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are using "onNavigatedTo", not "onNavigatingTo" ?

These are all [page events](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/tns-core-modules/ui/page/page.d.ts#L64-L82).

Comment: Checked and yes I'm using that.